# problems with an asp include file-

Tags: asp-classic

I'm having problems with an #include asp file. I was trying to add the following file to a classic asp page:

```vbs
<%
Function URLDecode(sConvert)
    Dim aSplit
    Dim sOutput
    Dim I
    If IsNull(sConvert) Then
        URLDecode = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' convert all pluses to spaces
    sOutput = REPLACE(sConvert, "+", " ")

    ' next convert %hexdigits to the character
    aSplit = Split(sOutput, "%")

    If IsArray(aSplit) Then
        sOutput = aSplit(0)
        For I = 0 to UBound(aSplit) - 1
            sOutput = sOutput & _
                Chr("&H" & Left(aSplit(i + 1), 2)) &_
                Right(aSplit(i + 1), Len(aSplit(i + 1)) - 2)
        Next
    End If

    URLDecode = sOutput
End Function    

Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim I
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"    , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"    , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))
    For I = 1 to 255
        sText = Replace(sText, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
    Next
    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function                    
%>
```

When I add this to the body, it does as expected:

```
<!--#include virtual src=".../url-html-decode.asp"-->
```

However, when there is another include asp file in the body, it will not run.We are using teamsite cms.

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Here is the include.asp file:

```
 <%
 dim URLlinks,appType,appAcceptURL,appCancelURL,pageActionLinks,dynamicCancelURL          ,subPage,appBackURL,refid,appGid,pageHeader,pageActionButtons,dynamicBackURL,         dynamicAcceptURL, dynamicCanceltURL
appType = Request.QueryString("SRC")
appBacKURL = Request.QueryString("CANCEL")
appAcceptURL = Request.QueryString("ACCEPT")
appCancelURL = Request.QueryString("CANCEL")
csrf = Request.QueryString("csrf")
appGid = Request.QueryString("gid")
subPage = Request.QueryString("subpage")
pageHeader = Request.QueryString("pageheader")
pageActionLinks = Request.QueryString("actionlinks")

dynamicBACKURL = appCancelURL & "?gid=" & appGid & "&" & csrf
dynamicAcceptURL = appAcceptURL & "?gid=" & appGid & "&" & csrf
dynamicCancelURL = appCancelURL & "?gid=" & appGid & "&" & csrf

If subPage = "true" Then
dynamicBACKURL=Request.QueryString("SUBCANCEL")
End If

URLlinks = "?SRC=" & appType & "&pageheader=" & pageHeader & "&actionlinks=" &         pageActionLinks & "&csrf=" & Server.URLEncode(csrf) & "&SUBCANCEL=" &         Server.URLEncode(Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?" & Request.Querystring & Request.Form     )& "&ACCEPT=" & Server.URLEncode(appAcceptURL) & "&gid=" & appGid &     "&subpage=true"


Dim user_agent, Regex, match
user_agent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
Set Regex = New RegExp
With Regex
   .Pattern = "(ipad)"
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .Global = True
End With

If appType = "BASE" Then %>
<link type="text/css" href="/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection,     print" />
<%
end if

match = Regex.Test(user_agent)
If appType = "APP" Then
If match Then %>
<link type="text/css" href="/css/ipad.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection,    print">
<% end if
end if

Set Regex = New RegExp
With Regex
   .Pattern = "(iphone)"
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .Global = True
End With

match = Regex.Test(user_agent)

If appType = "APP" Then
If match Then %>
<link type="text/css" href="/css/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,    projection, print">
<% end if
end if
Set Regex = New RegExp
With Regex
   .Pattern = "(android)"
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .Global = True
End With

match = Regex.Test(user_agent)

 If appType = "APP" Then
 If match Then %>
 <link type="text/css" href="/css/android.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,      projection, print">
 <% end if
 end if

 If appType = "WEBKIT" Then %>
 <link type="text/css" href="/css/touch.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,     projection, print">
<% end if
If subPage = "true" Then %>
<script>subpage=1;</script>
<% end if  %>
```

I have integrated both of these into one include.asp page, but it only works if there are no other `<% %>` tags in the body. The only way I can get both include files to work is to put it right after the body tag, but the cms person says she cannot do that due to site publisher.  Strange.  In addition, putting `<!-- include virtual src=etc"-->` referencing the first page in the second page does not work.

Any thoughts regarding this strangeness?

I tried to do this:

```
<script language=vbscript runat=server src=/asp/url-html-decode.asp"></script>
```

But i get the following error:

> microsoft vbscript compilation (0x800A0400) Expected statement /asp/usrl-html-decode.asp, line 1 %>

Why am I getting this error? Sorry for the verboseness here.

Comment: What syntax are you using for the include?

Comment: I am using this: <!-- #include virtual="/includes/asp/url-html-decode.asp" --> The other asp file is based on this url both the url decode and the html decode: http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp Thanks